# How to conditionally select elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can someone help me with conditionally selecting elements in a numpy array? I am trying to return elements that are greater than a threshold. My current solution is:

```
sampleArr = np.array([ 0.725, 0.39, 0.99 ])
condition = (sampleArr > 0.5)`
extracted = np.extract(condition, sampleArr) #returns [0.725 0.99]
```

However, this seems roundabout and I suspect there's a way to do it in one line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can index directly like:

```
sampleArr[sampleArr > 0.5]
```

#### Test Code:

```
sampleArr = np.array([0.725, 0.39, 0.99])

condition = (sampleArr > 0.5)
extracted = np.extract(condition, sampleArr)  # returns [0.725 0.99]

print(sampleArr[sampleArr > 0.5])
print(sampleArr[condition])
print(extracted)
```

#### Results:

```
[ 0.725  0.99 ]
[ 0.725  0.99 ]
[ 0.725  0.99 ]
```

Comment: why 2d array select becomes 1d array？

Comment: @CSQGB I do not see any 2d arrays here.

Comment: what about multiple conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually just do boolean indexing like this:

```
extracted = sampleArr[sampleArr > 0.5]
```

Comment: You have the same answer :P

Comment: why 2d array select becomes 1d array？`z=numpy.random.randint(1,9,(4,4))` z[z>4]   array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])         . Not 2d array

Comment: @CSQGB Not a real explanation but this can never work since it would generally have to result in rows/columns of uneven length. You can use `np.argwhere`to find positions of elements satisfying the condition or use the `z>4` mask and loop through it when required.