# List (data) and returns a list of only those entries x of data for which |x−μ|<M α_μ (and that occur in the same order as they occur in the data)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, physics

This question is confusing me a little on how to interpret x, so far I've done as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def keep(data, M):

    array_DATA = np.array(data)
    
    N = len(data)
    std = np.std(data)
    
    stderr = (std)/(np.sqrt(N-1))
    mean = (sum(data))/N
    
    L = abs((array_DATA)-(mean))
    R = (M)*(stderr)
    
    for i in range(0, N):
        if L < R:
            x = np.append(x, data[i])
    return (list(x))
```

for a standard error function, can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Well, your loop is clearly wrong, because the "if" statement will be the same every time.  By the way, L is an array, so I don't think "L < R" is what you want.  `L[i]` maybe?  I can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim Roberts commented there is an error in your final selection of data points, your code was nearly there but not quite, it seems like you confused then functionality of the python `list` and `numpy.array`, which has the great feature of conditional selection (you can read more about it here [How to conditionally select elements in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610136/how-to-conditionally-select-elements-in-numpy-array/48610172)), so changing the for loop for just `x = arr[L < R]` will do what you intended, all the elements of `L` get compared with `R` and the resulting array is used to index your `arr` variable, and the elements that get matched with a `True` are selected.

I also want to comment that since you imported `numpy` and you make a `numpy.array` from the input data, that you use it more, since your code will likely run much faster for larger data sets because `numpy.array` is vectorized.

So doing a little change to the final selection of data your code should be

```py
import numpy as np


def keep(data, M):

    arr = np.array(data)
    
    N = len(arr)
    std = arr.std()
    
    stderr = std / np.sqrt(N - 1)
    mean = arr.sum() / N
    
    L = abs(arr - mean)
    R = M * stderr

    x = arr[L < R]

    return list(x)


print(keep(range(6), 2))
```

In the case that you don't want to use a `numpy.array` and rather stick to python `list` this code does the same calculations

```
def keep_list_based(data, M):

    N = len(data)
    std = np.std(data)
    
    stderr = std / np.sqrt(N - 1)
    mean = sum(data) / N
    
    L = [abs(point - mean) for point in data]
    R = M * stderr

    # equivalent to x = data[L < R]
    bool_mask = [y < R for y in L]
    x = [point for point, passed_condition in zip(data, bool_mask) if passed_condition]
    
    return x


print(keep_list_based(list(range(6)), 2))
```

here `bool_mask = [y < R for y in L]` makes a boolean list of the points that satisfy the condition, and `x = [point for point, passed_condition in zip(data, bool_mask) if passed_condition]` filters the points in `data` according to the previous boolean list, using `zip` to pair the two lists.